# Browser support for margin: auto

Tags: css, browser-support

Like many designers I use `margin: 0 auto;` to center an element. While trying to check the browser support for this feature at http://www.caniuse.com I was unable to find anything related.

Is there a browser compatibility matrix for this feature?

Comment: If you can't find it on `caniuse`, then you may assume it is supported by everything. Except maybe IE6 because screw IE6...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, I read somewhere about some issues with older Android versions of Opera or Chrome - I can't remember.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you probably don't want to adjust your code to work in antique browsers that don't support `margin: 0 auto;`, but since you asked:

Support started only with IE6. If you want to support earlier browsers, you can add `text-align: center;` to the parent element. This works because old browsers incorrectly apply `text-align` also to block-elements. At the same time, keep `margin: 0 auto;` for modern browsers. If you want `text-align: center` to work in modern browser as well, you can also set `display: inline-block;` - then you won't need `margin: 0 auto;`.

So assuming this is your HTML:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

you have these options:

### Option 1

```
#outer {
    background: pink;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center; /* for very old browsers */
}

#inner {
    background: green;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto; /* for >99% of browsers */
}
```

### Option 2

```
#outer {
    background: pink;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px; /* height of child - necessary for IE8 and IE9,
    otherwise the height is slightly larger than that of the child */
}

#inner {
    background: green;
    display: inline-block; /* necessary for modern browsers, IE8+ */
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

But as I said, before supporting such ancient browsers, you may really think if the extra effort is worth it, or if it's better to just drop support for them.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you!

Comment: Another one question: What's up with cross-browser support of `width: auto;`?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are asking? As far as I know, `width: auto;` is supported by all browsers and also happens to be [the initial value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width). To calculate the auto width for block elements, substract horizontal margins/padding/borders from the parent element's width. For inline elements, the auto width is simply the width of the content. It's as if you don't set any width at all.

Comment: Yes, there is reason. I am developing a HTML5 framework and I'm relying heavily on `margin: 0 auto` and `width: auto;` rules. I'm targeting Android Browser 2.3+ so I have to avoid such handy things like `calc()`.

Comment: Have you encountered any problems with `width: auto;`? As far as I know, it should work fine among all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/margin , all browser support `margin: 0 auto;` fully.

Comment: The answer is wrong. Some old browsers do not support `margin: 0 auto;`, and this is also indicated in the cited source. See my answer for a more details.