# Bootstrap 4, How do I center-align a button?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8">
      <div v-for="job in job">
        <div class="text-center">
          <h1>{{ job.job_title }}</h1>
          <p><strong>Google Inc. </strong> - {{ job.location }}</p>
          <h2><u>Job Description</u></h2>
        </div>
        <p v-html="desc"></p>
        <p class="text-center">Posted: {{ formatDate(job.date_created) }}</p>
        <button v-on:click="applyResume()" id="apply-btn" class="btn btn-primary">{{ buttonText }}</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden-sm-down col-md-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can't figure out how to center this button. In BS 3 I would just use center-block but that's not an option in BS4. Any advice?

Comment: for bootstrap 5                   ```<div  class=" row d-flex justify-content-center align-content-center "  >  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary col-3">Button</a>  </div>```

Answer (score 356, accepted):

In Bootstrap 4 one should use the `text-center` class to align ***inline-blocks***.

NOTE: `text-align:center;` defined in a custom class you apply to your parent element will work regardless of the Bootstrap version you are using. And that's exactly what `.text-center` applies.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col text-center">
      <button class="btn btn-default">Centered button</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If the content to be centered is ***block*** or ***flex*** (not `inline-`), one could use flexbox to center it:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
  <button class="btn btn-default">Centered button</button>
</div>
```

... which applies `display: flex; justify-content: center` to parent.

**Note:** don't use `.row.justify-content-center` instead of `.d-flex.justify-content-center`, as `.row` applies negative margins on certain responsiveness intervals, which results into unexpected horizontal scrollbars (unless `.row` is a direct child of `.container`, which applies lateral padding to counteract the negative margin, on the correct responsiveness intervals). If you must use `.row`, for whatever reason, override its margin and padding with `.m-0.p-0`, in which case you end up with pretty much the same styles as `.d-flex`.

**Important note:** The second solution is problematic when the centered content (the button) exceeds the width of the parent (`.d-flex`) especially when the parent has viewport width, specifically because it makes it impossible to horizontally scroll to the start of the content (left-most).
So don't use it when the content to be centered could become wider than the available parent width and all content should be accessible.

Comment: Nevermind, I was just being dumb and put row inside of col rather than col inside row.

Answer (score 57):

Try this with bootstrap

#### CODE:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">btnText</button>
</div>
```

#### LINK:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#variable-width-content

Comment: Nothing else worked, even manually giving the styles to the object. But this works. Accept this answer.

Comment: Only this solution works, don't know why, but it is the truth

Answer (score 51):

With the use of the bootstrap 4 utilities you could horizontally center an element itself by setting the horizontal margins to 'auto'.

To set the horizontal margins to auto you can use `mx-auto` . The `m` refers to margin and the `x` will refer to the x-axis (left+right) and `auto` will refer to the setting. So this will set the left margin and the right margin to the 'auto' setting. Browsers will calculate the margin equally and center the element. The setting will only work on block elements so the display:block needs to be added and with the bootstrap utilities this is done by `d-block`.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mx-auto d-block">Submit</button>
```

You can consider all browsers to fully support auto margin settings according to this answer [Browser support for margin: auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36521797/browser-support-for-margin-auto) so it's safe to use.

The bootstrap 4 class `text-center` is also a very good solution, however it needs a parent wrapper element. The benefit of using auto margin is that it can be done directly on the button element itself.

Comment: This worked for me using Bootstrap 4 based Core UI Pro admin template

Comment: The cleanest solution in my opinion, only utilizing official Bootstrap classes.

Answer (score 34):

Here is the full HTML that I use to center by button in Bootsrap form
after closing form-group:

```
<div class="form-row text-center">
    <div class="col-12">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 17):

Use `text-center` class in the parent container for Bootstrap 4

Answer (score 2):

for a button in a collapsed navbar nothing above worked for me
so in my css file i did.....

```
.navbar button {
    margin:auto;
}
```

and it worked!!

Answer (score 2):

thing is you need to wrap your button in a parent element :

```
   ` <div class="text-center">
              <a href="./templatemo_558_klassy_cafe/index.html" class="btn btn- 
   outline-light me-5 ">Lavande Restaurant PH</a>`
             </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was (adapt "css/style.css" to your css path):

Head HTML:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" media="screen" />
```

Body HTML:

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="mycentered-text">
      <button class="btn btn-default"> Login </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.mycentered-text {
    text-align:center
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also just wrap with an H class or P class with a text-center attribute

Comment: If you do not give a specific answer, and only suggest how it could solve this problem, write it in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Its Easy

```
<div class="align-self-center mx-auto">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                  Click Me!
              </button>
 </div>
```