# Trying to center a bootstrap button (avoid "full width")

Tags: bootstrap-4

This code (using bootstrap 4) makes the button go full-width.

How do I make the button just fit the text that it is in? I think it need to place it in a column?

```
  <section class="call-to-action text-white text-center">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-12" style="text-align:center">
          <h1>Bunch of text Bunch of text Bunch of text Bunch of text Bunch of text Bunch of text Bunch of text</h1>
          <a href="#scrolltotop" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-danger" style="margin-top:40px";>Find Out Now!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Thanks for all help with this - I'm very new to Bootsrap 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `btn-block` and `col-xs-**` is dropped in V4. It's replaced by `col-**`

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<section class="call-to-action text-white text-center">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12" style="text-align:center">
          <h1 style="color:black">Bunch of text Bunch of text Bunch of text Bunch of text Bunch of text Bunch of text Bunch of text</h1>
          <a href="#scrolltotop" class="btn btn-md btn-danger" style="margin-top:40px";>Find Out Now!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

This another question can help people that could not resolve the problem: [Bootstrap 4, How do I center-align a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41664991/bootstrap-4-how-do-i-center-align-a-button)

In summary you need to add the button inside a div with `class = "col"`. Like:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col text-center">
      <button class="btn">BUTTON</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```