# centering bootstrap button under text centered in page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to add a button under some text in a contact section. the text says get in touch in the center of the page and when I add a button it goes under the test but to the left. I want it center of the page under the text.

```
<section class="contact" id="contact">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 p-lg-6 mx-auto my-5">
      <h1 class="text-capitalize text-center about-banner">
        get <strong class="text-center about-banner-two">in touch</strong>
      </h1>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary text-uppercase">contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just put it in an element (paragraph, div, whatever) and use `text-center`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap 4, How do I center-align a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41664991/bootstrap-4-how-do-i-center-align-a-button)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!----------------- JUST ADD THIS CLASS  ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓ -->
<div class="col-md-6 p-lg-6 mx-auto my-5 text-center">
  <h1 class="text-capitalize text-center about-banner">
    get <strong class="text-center about-banner-two">in touch</strong>
  </h1>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary text-uppercase">contact</a>
</div>
```